# How to use parent loop counter in the nested for-loop to access to a specific row in a json like data in django templates (.html file)

Tags: arrays, django, for-loop, templates, templatetags

at the following code the interior for loop needs to access to a specific row of entries.
In the other words the nested loop should be  {% for entry in entries.(topic.id) %}
the entries is a JSON like array as the following:

```
entries = [
    {'a', 'b', 'c'},
    {'d'},
    {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'},
    {'j','k'}
    .
    .
    .
]
```

```
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
        <h5>
            {{topic.id}} - {{topic}}
            <ul>
                <small>
                {% with i=topic.id %}
                
                {{i}}
                {% for entry in entries.i %}
                    <li>{{forloop.counter}} . {{entry}}</li>
                {% empty %}
                    <li>No entries available!</li>
                {% endfor %}

                {% endwith %}
                </small>
            </ul>

        </h5>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        <h4 style="color: tomato;">There is no available topic(s)</h4>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show the part of your view where you where you define `topics` and `entries`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt follow up, but I managed to found the solution and write down the answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

A custom template tag fixed my issue.
Refer to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def topicID(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]
```

And by apply this filter to the nested for-loop my issue has been solved, my code is now as following:

```
    {% for topic in topics %}
    <li>
        <h5>
            {{forloop.counter}} - {{topic}}
            <ul>
                <small>
                {% for entry in entries|topicID:forloop.counter0%}
                    <li>{{forloop.counter}} . {{entry}}</li>
                {% empty %}
                    <li>No entries available!</li>
                {% endfor %}

                </small>
            </ul>

        </h5>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
    <li>
        <h4 style="color: tomato;">There is no available topic(s)</h4>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: A custom template tag for this is a bit overkill, as a tip try using `zip(topics, entries)` and passing this in the context. Then you can simply loop as `{% for topic, entry in zip_object %}`